# Should mods upvote featured meta posts?

Tags: discussion

The Community user just bumped an old Weekly Topic Challenge -- I assume it was due to lack of activity (zero upvotes on the original question and on the answer summarizing the results of the challenge).

As I understand it, upvoting a question is part of the algorithm that sends Meta posts out on the automatic Twitter feed.

So -- should we mods upvote the Meta questions tagged 'featured', in order to:

1. send them out on the Twitter feed when they are first posted (when the challenge is active) and
2. make it less likely that the Community user will stir them up from the past?

I don't want to delete old Meta questions, because that erases the history of the site.  What's the most appropriate way to handle this situation?

One possible workaround might be to explicitly put the date of the Weekly Topic Challenge in the question title, to make it more clear an old challenge is being bumped.  But I do see the virtue of bumping an old Topic Challenge, as a prompt to new users who might not have been here when it was first proposed.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I wish users of G&FH SE would be more generous with their upvotes to encourage more site participation, and to give the Community user less work like this to do.

Unless I have a significant issue with a post, I try to upvote all posts that I see here while we remain in Beta.

I don't think we should include timestamps in titles because having a question like a weekly topic challenge appear after that challenge is over may yet help trigger another question or two, and I think the biggest challenge our site faces is unlocking a steady flow of questions to attract new users and maintain the interest of existing ones.